# Mongo 3.4 to 3.6

Tags: mongodb, windows

How to upgrade 3.4 mongo to 3.6 mongo. I don't have config file while starting mongodb in 3.4 how to have it in windows locally.

Comment: See [Upgrade a Standalone to 3.6](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/)